# How to set Long value to primitive null in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to perform a database insert or update in Java.

The method receives `eventId` as `Long`.

My code essentially returns a `NullPointerException` when I run the following:

```java
if (!(eventId>0)) {
   eventId = null;
}
```

However I need the `eventId` set explicitly to `null` for an `insert` before it hits the database.

So the basic question is, how can I set `null` to the `Long` variable without it blowing up with a `NullPointerException` ?

Comment: If that code throws the exception, it was already null.

Comment: What piece of code exactly is throwing the NPE?

Comment: `!(eventId>0)` is more conventionally written as `eventId<=0`

Comment: It's literally what I wrote above. I am sorry, but I am kinda new to Java. I usually program in PHP, so I am a little lost on this thing. I tried using a primitive, but this doesn't accept null at all ...

Comment: 1) You should enable compiler warnings for Auto-Boxing and -Unboxing. Seriously. Then you'd see where the problems lie. 2) Your method likely does not **return** a `NullPointerException`, but rather **throw**, which is a serious difference. 3) `null` is not a *Java Primitive*, because it cannot be assigned to *any Primitive*, but to *ALL reference variables* 4) `if (eventId != null) eventId = null;`

Comment: If you don’t want an NPE, *test for null first.* But you don’t need a null variable to insert NULL into a database. You need the keyword NULL in the SQL.

Comment: @JayC667 you want your IDE to festoon your editor with a cavalcade of warnings for _every_ auto-(un)boxing? That's highly irregular; I'd wager less than 5% of all java programmers do that, if not less than 1%, and a ton of projects out there use autoboxing and unboxing, so, you'd get overrun with warnings if you open any other code. Do __not__ advise this to anybody, let alone newbies. If someone really really wants this, they'll figure it out on their own.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Actually, I do that for all my code. And yes, most foreign code uses it. If it's only a few instances, I patch that code. But even worse: That foreign code usually throws so much more warnings related to other things like overwriting parameters, unused variables, name shadowing, nullness, raw generic types etc. So this gives me a nice look into how old and how clean that code is, and usually it's... *hrmhrm*... And YES: I would definitely advise that to a newbie, because we already see in this example that it actually does cause problems. The sooner you get the basics right.. :-)

Comment: You act as if, say, 'overwriting parameters' is some sort of intrinsic failure. You're inventing rules, as they say. You think that's "basics"? This is very much fly by advice based on some off the cuff commentary, so take it with the requisite kilo of salt, but, strong sense of Cargo Cult Programming coming off of these ridiculous points of  view.

Answer (score 1):

If `eventId` is already `null`, `eventId>0` will throw an NPE.

The fix is trivial:

```
if (eventId != null && eventId <= 0) eventId = null;
```

NB: `!(eventId > 0)` is better written as `eventId <= 0` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows using the [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1.4) (aka the ternary operator) `?:` If the expression evaluates to true, it returns null, otherwise it returns the original `eventId`.

```
eventId = eventId != null && eventId <= 0 ? null : eventId;
```